# Zend Framework 2: Use SQL Select with multiple "OR" in Loop

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Iam new to Zend Framework 2, and have some trouble to create an WHERE SQL Statement with multiple "OR" clauses.

```
$ids = array("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7");

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $select->where->equalTo('id', $id);      
    // how to add OR for remaining ids
}
```

Is there any simple solution for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has worked for me  about a month ago. in version 2.2

```
$ids = array("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7");

$select->where->in('id', $ids);
```

Comment: Zend is beautiful but tricky and alot of work to know all work arounds

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SQL [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
$select->where('id IN (?)', $ids);
```

Comment: FYI this was the ZF1 syntax.